# Firebase Firestore query only returning one entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection set up as thus:

[image]

EDIT: As requested, here's a screenshot showing the second document which contains the same PostId and 'poster' as the single document being retrieved.

[image]

Now in this chats2 collection there are two documents with the same 'postId' and 'poster'. I am using the following query. Can anyone please show me why it is returning only one message?

```
async function getIndividualMessage() {

    try{
        return await useFireStore
        .collection('chats2')
        .where("postId", "==", `${postId}`)
        .where("poster", "==", `${posterId}`)
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let eachMessage = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                eachMessage.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
            });
            setTheMessageData(eachMessage);
        });
    }
    catch{
        console.log('error on getIndividualMessage')
    }
    finally{

    }
}
```

As far as I'm aware in the query I'm asking for all the entries where the postID = $postId and the poster = $posterId.

The value of console.log("the messagedata is :",theMessageData[0]) is:

```
the messagedata is : 
{createdAt: t, postId: "PsulTQciDB4iBfPQRUbn", poster: "VeFpTQuWlLc859TR8O3h9F10ky53", 
message: "Admin on Amazon 1", id: "QWHgZ6Z9JsmYLSiACUjT"}
createdAt: t {seconds: 1611056590, nanoseconds: 431000000}
id: "QWHgZ6Z9JsmYLSiACUjT"
message: "Admin on Amazon 1"
postId: "PsulTQciDB4iBfPQRUbn"
poster: "VeFpTQuWlLc859TR8O3h9F10ky53"
```

EDIT TWO: The result of console.log("the messagedata is :",theMessageData) is (hence the [0] in the first console log:

```
[{…}]
0:
createdAt: t {seconds: 1611056548, nanoseconds: 503000000}
id: "uu9QbeZncCBVdlPVDGe6"
message: "matt on Amazon 1"
postId: "PsulTQciDB4iBfPQRUbn"
poster: "WD3YintPmjhztE7horU8VpfOnoo1"
```

There should be two messages are there are two entries with those PostId and Poster values at the bottom. I've been on this for about the last four hours and I still can't figure it out. Is there something obviously wrong that I doing?

Any help very much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: Does the other document have a "createdAt" value?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, yes it does. The documents are the same apart from the 'message' and the 'createdAt' time. I'm basically trying to get a list of messages for that postID and that 'user' or 'poster'. It's really strange.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you post a screenshot of the other document too

Comment: Certainly, I've just added one. Thanks for your time Ahmed 

Comment: How are you checking the data length? Your log code shows `theMessageData[0]`, so it prints the first value.

Comment: I've just added an edit showing the results of console.log(theMessageData) without the [0]

Comment: Cool; I suspect the issue with the `forEach` loop; to find out, could you log the `snapshot.docs.length`. If the value is `> 1`, simply use for loop to iterate over the docs.

Comment: Hi Muthu. It's just 1. This is really odd. I tried deleting the entry it displays, and then it displays the second entry. So, we know that both entries match the search criteria, there's something somewhere which is stipulating it should only ever return one entry, or the first entry it comes to.

Comment: Which Firestore library are you using? [Firstore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore) or [Firebase Firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firestore), are you using the lastest version of the library? ,and this is a server function or is executed on the browser?

Comment: Hi Jan, I'm using Firebase 8.2.2, (installed last week, though I've just checked and the latest version is 8.2.4. It's not a server function, it's executed in one of my React components

Comment: I created a similar data structure, I used your code and all works as expected.

I changed the statement `setTheMessageData` to `console.log(eachMessage);` 

This is my environment, Debian 10, Node 10.23.1, Firebase 8.2.4, I'm not sure if this can help you.